# Delphi "loads" incorrect version of DevExpress components

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I have recently updated my version of the DevExpress components for Delphi from 15.1.2 to 15.1.6, but when launching Delphi XE8, I am presented with the "standard" procedure entry point not found

[image: Summary of what's installed and the error message]

As is shown here, version 2015.1.6 is installed, but 15.1.2 is trying to be loaded by Delphi XE8.  The versions of the bpl files in the DXVCL install folder are also 2015.1.6.

Things I have tried:

1. performing a "repair" on the DevExpress components
2. uninstalling the DevExpress components and re-installing them
3. uninstalling the DevExpress components and re-installing them as an Administrator
4. searching for "15.1.2" in files within the RAD Studio install folder, in case there was something hard-coded.

Comment: You didn't uninstall the old version properly. Uninstall DevEx from the IDE (Components->Install Components, remove the packages). Close the IDE. Uninstall DevEx from your drive. Search your entire hard disk (including your Users\YourUserName\Documents and Users\Public\Documents) folders) for any files matching any of the DevEx runtime or designtime packages and delete them. Start the IDE and make sure everything is gone. Then reinstall the DevEx components.

Comment: Its also a good idea to open Delphi after uninstalling and it will detect that the files are no longer there and prompt you on whether it should try load them next time

Comment: @Donovan: I said that: *Start the IDE and make sure everything is gone.*.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, my apologies, my comment was more to inform him that the IDE will prompt him whether to load the package next time

Answer (score 1):

The location which packages to load is stored in the registry.

For XE8 it is located in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\16.0\Known Packages`.

You should be able to spot the wrong ones there and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I found this procedure on DevExpress official support center. It should allow you correctly reinstalling DevExpress VCL products from scratch.

> 1. Completely uninstall our products by launching our VCL Installer in "Remove" mode;
> 2. Delete remaining files manually using the BPLFinder tool from the [FAQ: Migrating to the new version](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18485.aspx) Knowledge Base article; (NOTE: USE
>      BPLFinder; delete only **OUR** binary files; delete **ALL** our binary files
>      in the list);
> 3. Launch your IDE and delete invalid paths from its "Library path" and "Browsing path" lists;
> 4. Remove all custom packages (if any exist) based on our packages;
> 5. Close your IDE and remove invalid paths using the PATHEnvironmentVariablePatcher from the [FAQ: Migrating to the new version](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18485.aspx) Knowledge Base article;
> 6. Make sure that you have **ALL** available IDE updates installed.
> 7. Restart your PC;
> 8. Login into the system as Administrator and install our controls from scratch to the **C:\DevEx** folder or similar short-named folder. The
>      full path to the dxCoreRS16.bpl package should not contain spaces. I
>      strongly recommend the following resulting path:
>
> **C:\DevEx\Library\RS16\dxCoreRS16.bpl**

[Reinstalling VCL products from scratch](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q496450)

Let us know if it helped